# Limit of composite piecewise function

Tags: limits

[image: piece wise function]
Hello,

I was wondering how to solve: $$\lim_{x \to 0} f(f(x))$$ for the attached graph.

This is what I tried: 
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} f(f(x)) &= f\left[\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)\right] \\
&= f(2) = -1
\end{align}
but the correct answer is supposed to be $-2$, how do I arrive at that answer? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that since

$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=2$$

and in a deleted neighborhood of $x=2$ we have $f(x)<2$ then

$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(f(x))=\lim_{y\to 2^-} f(y)=-2$$

Comment: what does f(y) mean?

Comment: I’ve used $y$ to indicate $f(x)$ that is $y=f(x)\to 2^-$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ you have $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 2$. Furthermore, since $f(x) \le $ for all $|x| <1$ we see that as $x \to 0$ (but not equal to) we also have $f(x) < 2$.

Hence as $x \to 0$ we have $f(x) \uparrow 2$ (that is, less than as it approaches).

From the graph, we see that for $y \in (1,2)$ we have $f(y) = 2(1-y)$, hence we see that $f(f(x)) \to \lim_{y \uparrow 2} f(y) = -2$.

Comment: I don't get where  f(y)=2(1−y) comes from

Comment: Look at the graph, for $y \in (1,2)$, $f$ is a straight line, You don't need to work out a formula, it just makes it a little easier. Note that for $x \in [0,2)$, $f$ is a straight line that passes through $(0,2), (1,0)$. The basic point is that $f(x)$ tends to 2 from below, so $f(f(x))$ will tend to $-2$.